# How to mock a function imported from inside another function or method?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I don't make a habit of this, but sometimes, in an effort to work around a circular import, I'll import a function from inside another function or method like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        from somewhere import the_thing
        x = the_thing()
        return x + 4
```

This works just fine, but I can't figure out how to test it.  My usual fails with complaints that `module "xyz" has no attribute "the_thing"`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch("path.to.my.module.the_thing")
    def test_stuff(self):
        ...
```

Is there a way to mock functions imported at runtime?  Is there a Better Way to do this?

Comment: Two options that aren't really answers but are IMO good things to consider nevertheless: avoid circular imports (i.e. reorganize your code so that it's "layered" and circular dependencies between modules aren't a thing), or use dependency injection so that you don't need to patch in your tests.  (These may be one and the same;  when you have layered code and something in a lower layer needs a function from a higher layer, dependency injection is how you do that.  The crucial thing is that the lower layer doesn't *explicitly* depend on the higher layer.)

Answer (score 1):

I have created following files in my system.

```
|-module
|   |- __init__.py
|   |- my_class.py
|   |- xyz.py
|- test_my_class.py
```

`module` is a folder with inside the file `my_class.py` and the module `xyz.py` besides that the empty file `__init__.py`.
The *production code* inside the package `module` is the following.

File `xyz.py`:

```
def the_thing():
    return 6
```

File `my_class.py`:

```
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        from module.xyz import the_thing
        x = the_thing()
        return x + 4
```

The content of the file `test_my_class.py` is:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from module.my_class import MyClass

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("module.xyz.the_thing")
    def test_stuff(self, mock_thing):
        mock_thing.return_value = 20
        self.assertEqual(24, MyClass().my_method())

    def test_stuff_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(10, MyClass().my_method())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see the test file defines 2 tests and only in the first test (`test_stuff()`) is used the patch() function:

- by `patch()` is defined the Mock object `mock_thing`;
- in the method `test_stuff()` is defined the `return_value` of the function `the_thing()`

The second test method calls `my_method()` and verifies its normal return value.

I hope the previous code answers your question.